How to disable the service (SPI) registration of a specific java library?
Currently we are deleting the META-INF/services folder from the jar, but I was wondering if there was a less intrusive way?
E.g. this library provides 2 versions: One with and one without the services directory (lib.jar vs lib-spi-off.jar): https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-testng/2.21.0/
Context: We need to use a library that has a transitive dependency to some version of xercesImpl, which registers itself as SAXParser service provider. Because of a rather complex classloader situation we would like to ensure that this xerces version does not register itself because we want to avoid runtime surprises in other parts of the application that use xml (unrealistic to know/test all of those).

It would be good if you clarify why are trying to do this, to provide context and to avoid XYProblems.

@aled tnx for reading the question. i had to google "xy-problem". i will add context but would prefer help for this question, even if my current specific context / root cause might have other solutions (which I am investigating separately).

I don't know if it's possible to disable that, but during the build you can try excluding that folder in META-INF using the Maven Shade Plugin.
<executions>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
</executions>


Thank you, but the question is if there are other ways than removing the META-INF/services directory.
